# OpenAPI (Swagger) not working correctly with array type

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I using `SpringBoot` and `springdoc-openapi-ui`. I have controller with method, which contain array as url param:

```java
 @Parameters(value = {
            @Parameter(in = ParameterIn.QUERY, name = "output", example = "[f1,f2,f3]",
                    content = @Content(array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(type = "string"))))
})
public ResponseEntity<Object> showReportData(@RequestParam(value = "output") String[] outputFields) {
//some body
}
```

But, when I open `SwaggerUI`, I can't see my example values in items textbox:
[image]

And when I click execute, I see this param in request:
[image]

Why is this happening? Why is the example array not displayed in item?

Answer (score 0):

This seems more an issue related to your browser configuration.
Try to change the browser...

Arrays are working like a chamr in the swagger-ui.